# Dojo tree parent node

Tags: dojo, tree, widget

I was wondering if anyone had a way to get the parent node of an item in a dojo tree? I have tried but it doesn't seem to work.

I have tried a few different ways.

First I tried this:

```
this.tree.get("path")[this.tree.get("path").length - 2];
```

Next I tried what I found on this site: http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/how-do-I-get-the-parent-node-of-a-dijit-Tree-node-td1788430.html\

Neither one seems to work. I don't know why this is such a complicated thing when it is presumably a pretty common operation. If you could help me with this that would be awesome.

Thanks

EDIT: I guess what's throwing me off even more is that the method I tried first (the code sample provided) sometimes work. So this is really confusing me.

Answer (score 1):

Using Dojo v1.7, I have used:

```
// Very similar to your code (maybe even functionally equivalent)
tree.path[tree.path.length - 2];
```

That code has since been refactored away, but I'm pretty sure it worked.  Some of the things to be aware of with this is 1) I think this only works if the item whose parent you are looking for needs to be a selected item (tree.selectedItems[0]) and 2) this line might not work if your selected item is the tree's root (or the top level item if the root is hidden).